# Rudin's RCA Corollary theorem of $2.22$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

There is the theorem $2.22$ :

If $A$ $\subset$ $R^1$ and every subset of $A$ is Lebesgue measurable then $m(A)$ $=$ $0$.

This theorem has Corollary theorem.
There it is:

Every set of positive measure has nonmeasurable subsets.

There  is my question:

Corollary theorem means  that  $2.22$ implies this - Every set of positive measure has nonmeasurable subsets.

I understand the proof of $2.22$ but I couldn't understand why does it imply the corollary theorem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What in particular is confusing to you?

Comment: What about the contrapositive statement?

Comment: If every subset was measurable, it would imply $m(A)=0$, Which contradicts your assumption

Comment: @Oria [0,1] has positive measure . [0,1/5] is subset of [0,1] and it has measure of 1/5 . So how is it non-measurable?

Comment: @ColeG97 see my comment

Comment: The corollary does not state that every set of positive measure contains *only* non-measurable sets. It also contains some measurable subsets too. ¶ The basic principle of logic is the contrapositive, as @ALNS mentioned. If a set contains no non-measurable subsets, it is of zero measure. Therefore (contrapositive): If it is not of zero measure, it contains at least one non-measurable subset.

Comment: @BrianTung okay then look at the theorem not corollary. every subset of $[0,1]$ is lebesgue measurable but $m([0,1])$ $=$ $1$

Comment: That is not true if we assume the axiom of choice (which we usually do, and I'm assuming Rudin does?). See, for example, the [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set). These set demonstrations are usually non-constructive; nevertheless, they exist under ZFC.